# Batch edit in MEAN STACK angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, angular-xeditable

I am using MEAN STACK Technology .I try to create a batch edit functionality like i refer following link

I create it's come's row edit functionality like this
https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-row

I need like this 
https://distribution.frepple.com/data/input/demand/